# XML parser in Java

Tags: java, xml

I need to parse `xml` in `java`, can some one help me? My `xml` is

```
<books>
<book1>
<index1>title1</index1>
<index2>title2</index2>
<index3>
<data1>HI1</data1>
<index4>
<data2>HI2</data2>
</index4>
</index3>
<book1>
</books>
```

Output should be

```
books-book-begin
books-book-index1:title1
books-book-index2:title2
books-book-index3-begin
books-book-index3-data1:HI1
books-book-index3-index4-begin
books-book-index3-index4-HI2
books-book-index3-index4-end
books-book-index3-end
books-book-end
```

We will not print `begin` and `end` for `books` as it's the root tag.
Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it seems to be a homework or something where the parsing itself is important, I would use a SaxParser with your own handler, for example `MySAXHandler extends DefaultHandler`, then writing something like...

```
InputStream input = ...; //Your input here.

SAXParser      saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
MySAXHandler handler   = new MySAXHandler ();
saxParser.parse(input, handler);
```

You'll find that the handler has all the important methods for your task, I think.

If only the data is important, I would use JAXB, which is, if you ask me, much easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for you your but my xml should not be dependent on class, if new add new tags in xml , my class needs to be modified which i dont want.

Comment: Then the SAXParser is your way to got, as the handler will be informed about start-end of tags but does not rely on the exact structure.

Comment: i am able to parse XML but its printing wrong output, its should print like this:                                                                books-book-begin
books-book-begin
books-book-index1:title1
books-book-index2:title2
books-book-index3-begin
books-book-index3-data1:HI1
books-book-index3-index4-begin
books-book-index3-index4-HI2
books-book-index3-index4-end
books-book-index3-end
books-book-end                                                                             but its printing books-book-begin
books-book-index1:title1->begin
books-book-index2:title2->begin

Answer (score 0):

Use Jaxb
Convert XML to Object.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: like as,books-book-begin
books-book-index1:title1
books-book-index2:title2
books-book-index3-begin
books-book-index3-data1:HI1
books-book-index3-index4-begin
books-book-index3-index4-HI2
books-book-index3-index4-end
books-book-index3-end
books-book-end